# Segmentation fault (core dumped) not able to debug the code for binary search with duplicates problem?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, data-structures

the problem is to return the lowest index of the element on a sorted list with duplicates.
but my code is giving segmentation error.I am not able to identify the error in code.

```
int binary_search(const vector<int> &a, int left, int right, int x)
{
    // write your code here
    if (right - left == 0)
        return right;
    while (right >= left)
    {
        int mid = right - left / 2;
        if (a[mid] == x)
            return binary_search(a, left, mid, x);
        else if (a[mid] > x)
            right = mid - 1;
        else
            left = mid + 1;
    }
    return -1;
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    vector<int> a(n);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < a.size(); i++)
    {
        std::cin >> a[i];
    }
    int m;
    std::cin >> m;
    vector<int> b(m);
    for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i)
    {
        std::cin >> b[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i)
    {
        // replace with the call to binary_search when implemented
        std::cout << binary_search(a, 0, (int)a.size() - 1, b[i]) << ' ';
    }
}
```

Comment: input data? please add to post

Comment: Is your solution supposed to be *iterative* (using loops), or *recursive*? Why do you have both? Especially, why do you call `binary_search` recursively when you actually find the element you're looking for?

Comment: I believe that your calculation of mid is wrong and as a result you have an infinite recursion which is being stopped by a ... stack overflow.

Comment: I don't understand: `if (a[mid] == x) { binary_search(/*...*/)}`, why are you recursing if the value is found?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews duplicates are allowed, so finding a match isn't necessarily the desired first occurrence of that value.

Comment: If you want to find the first occurrence of a suite of duplicate values, once you have found one match then just loop backward (from `mid` to `left`) until you find a different value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you find the result `a[mid] == x`, store it & keep searching to the left portion for the lowest index.

```
int binary_search(const vector<int> &a, int left, int right, int x)
{
    // write your code here
    if (right - left == 0)
        return right;
    int idx = -1;

    while (right >= left)
    {
        int mid = right - left / 2;
        // modified
        if (a[mid] == x) {
            idx = mid;
            right = mid - 1;
        }
        else if (a[mid] > x)
            right = mid - 1;
        else
            left = mid + 1;
    }
    return idx;
}
```

P.S: You might want to check the way you're calculating `mid` value!
Usually, `mid = (left + right) / 2` or `mid = left + (right - left) / 2` to avoid overflow.

Comment: OP wants to find the leftmost equal element with the recursion, duplicates are allowed.